# Query Many to Many in Datastore with Filter

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, many-to-many, google-cloud-datastore

I have to 2 entity models

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    # other properties

class Item(ndb.Model):
    type = ndb.StringProperty()
    # other properties
```

with a many to many relationship between `User` and `Item`

```
class UserItem(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    item = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Item)
    # other properties
```

How can I query `UserItem` with a filter to `Item.type`. Something like `select * from UserItem where UserItem.user = user_key and UserItem.item.type = item_type`.

I know I can do it with `StructuredProperty` but there is an entity limit of 1mb. If it's not possible with the model how should I model the relationship to get get the query with filter work in datastore?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can't* do this, and you shouldn't try. The datastore is not a relational database, and shouldn't be used as one.

Rather than having a linking UserItem table, you should consider storing a list of keys in one of the entities. For example, you could add a field to User:

```
items = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Item, repeated=True)
```

and then with your User object, get the items by key and filter out the ones you need:

```
user_items = ndb.get_multi(my_user.items)
relevant_items = [item for item in user_items if item.type == my_type]
```

The exact structure is going to depend on your use-case, but the point is not to think in terms of traditional relationships like you would in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the filtering happens outside datastore? Is it efficient? Let's say we have #items > 1000 for a user. Could I model it with ancestor key (parent)

Comment: Sure, or even a KeyProperty from Item to User, but either way it's no longer a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: `user_items = ndb.get_multi(my_user.items)
relevant_items = [item for item in user_items if item.type == my_type]` using like this for #items > 1000. what about the performance? can I sort the list with this way?